VipsJpeg: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80
When running this github.com/davidbyttow/govips package within a Gin backend server, facing the below error:
VipsJpeg: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80

When running the same code as a script, it works fine and there is no error.
Steps to Reproduce:
Run a Gin backend server with github.com/davidbyttow/govips package.
Attempt to process JPEG images within the server.
Expected Behavior:
The server should run successfully without encountering any version mismatch errors related to the JPEG library.
Actual Behavior:
The server encounters the VipsJpeg: Wrong JPEG library version error, indicating a mismatch between the JPEG library versions.
Additional Context:
govips version: vips-8.15.0
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 arm64
Go version: go1.22.2
Sample Code:
    vips.Startup(nil)
    defer vips.Shutdown()

    daata, _ := os.ReadFile("sample.jpg")

    inputImage, err := vips.NewImageFromBuffer(daata)
    checkError(err)
    defer inputImage.Close()
    checkError(inputImage.OptimizeICCProfile())

    ep := vips.NewJpegExportParams()
    ep.StripMetadata = true
    ep.Quality = 75
    ep.Interlace = true
    ep.OptimizeCoding = true
    ep.SubsampleMode = vips.VipsForeignSubsampleAuto
    ep.TrellisQuant = true
    ep.OvershootDeringing = true
    ep.OptimizeScans = true
    ep.QuantTable = 3

    imageBytes, _, err := inputImage.ExportJpeg(ep)
    checkError(err)
    checkError(os.WriteFile("optim.jpg", imageBytes, 0644))

Debug Logs (From script):
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] found /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] using configure-time prefix
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] VIPS_PREFIX = /usr/local
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] VIPS_LIBDIR = /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] prefix = /usr/local
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] libdir = /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] searching "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] loading "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15/vips-openslide.so"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] loading "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15/vips-heif.so"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] loading "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15/vips-magick.so"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] loading "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-modules-8.15/vips-poppler.so"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [VIPS.info] searching "/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/vips-plugins-8.15"
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] vips 8.15.0 started with concurrency=1 cache_max_files=0 cache_max_mem=52428800 cache_max=100
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=tiff
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=heif
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=heif
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=svg
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=jpeg
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=magick
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=pdf
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=png
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=webp
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=jp2k
        2024/04/29 11:41:12 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=gif

**Logs (Gin Backend Server):
**
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] vips 8.15.0 started with concurrency=1 cache_max_files=0 cache_max_mem=52428800 cache_max=100
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=tiff
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=webp
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=heif
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=gif
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=magick
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=svg
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=heif
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=jp2k
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=jpeg
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=pdf
2024/04/30 05:45:51 [govips.info] registered image type loader type=png


anyone who feels responsible for the [tag:vips] or [tag:libvips] tags: perhaps request merging and aliasing on meta

This is a libjpeg feature -- 1) when you build libjpeg it makes a note of the libjpeg version number in the binary, 2) when you compile a program that uses libjpeg, it makes a note of the libjpeg version you built against, 3) when your program starts up, it checks that your program was built against the libjpeg it's linked to at runtime. So ... you probably have some code built for an old libjpeg that you are trying to run against a recent libjpeg. Check your system for duplicate libraries and rebuild stuff that's out of date.
